# USB Keyboard stops Windows 10 from sleeping

Tags: windows-10, usb, sleep, usb-keyboard

I recently got a USB wired keyboard (a Keychron V1). When I leave this plugged in it appears to stop my Win 10 laptop (a Dell Precision 5530) from sleeping, ie, if I unplug it my laptop sleeps as normal but if I leave it plugged in my computer does not go to sleep, and even seems to wake from sleep if I put it to sleep manually. Previously I’ve always had wireless keyboards so I am not sure if this is an issue with this specific keyboard or my laptop and wired keyboards in general. Why this might be happening and what can I do to stop it?

Comment: Have you asked Keychron?  Sounds like v1 mistake to me.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, but they haven't got back to me yet. Having done a bit more digging it looks like there are other people with this issue with QMK/VIA boards.